# Café com leite ou Leite-com-café?

Tags: ordem-de-expressões

Em inglês, quando escrevemos, a ordem dos adjetivos importa. Por exemplo: *sad little green dragon* não deve ser escrito *green sad little dragon*. Em português, existe tal regra e, existindo, qual é a versão correta: café com leite ou leite com café?

Comment: You are asking about adjectives but there is not a single adjective in your drinks. Which is correct in English - coffee with milk or milk with coffee?

Comment: Na teoria, acredito que 1o seria o que teria mais quantidade... café com leite, significaria que tem mais café do que leite e leite com café, teria mais leite que café. Por outro lado, nunca tinha ouvido leite com café.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Café com leite ou leite-com-café?**

**BINÔMIOS IRREVERSÍVEIS** - São grupos de duas (binômios) ou três palavras (trinômios) usadas em uma sequência consagrada pelos falantes de uma língua. Geralmente as duas (ou três) palavras são ligadas por **"e"**, **"ou"**, **"com"**, **"mas"**, ou uma outra conjunção.

> - Em linguística e estilística , um **binomial irreversível** , binomial (congelado) , par binomial , expressão binomial , congelamento (binomial) ou par de palavras não reversíveis, **é um par ou grupo de palavras usadas juntas em ordem fixa como uma expressão idiomática ou colocação** . As palavras pertencem à mesma classe gramatical, têm alguma relação semântica e geralmente são conectadas pelas palavras *e* ou *ou* .

> - O termo "binômio irreversível" foi introduzido por Yakov Malkiel em 1954, embora vários aspectos do fenômeno tenham sido discutidos desde pelo menos 1903 sob diferentes nomes: um "imbróglio terminológico". Ernest Gowers usou o nome *gêmeos siameses* na edição de 1965, de Fowler. A edição de 2015 volta ao nome acadêmico, "binômios irreversíveis", já que "gêmeos siameses" se tornou ofensivo para alguns. Muitos binômios irreversíveis são cativantes devido à aliteração ou rima , e muitos se tornaram clichês ou bordões onipresentes. **https://pt.qaz.wiki/wiki/Irreversible_binomial**

**Quando uma forma de expressar ou definir alguma coisa em uma determinada língua torna-se consagrada pelo uso, diz-se que aquela forma é idiomática. Independentemente de ter alguma lógica ou não, usa-se daquela forma e pronto, não tem discussão.**  Um bom exemplo é a expressão "long time, no see", da língua inglesa e que significa "há quanto tempo!" Apesar do protesto de alguns puristas por ferir a gramática, é assim que todos falam, e ponto final.

Alguns exemplos na língua portuguesa:

- em preto-e-branco
- com a cara e a coragem
- café-com-leite
- verde, amarelo, azul e branco
- bife com fritas
- casa e comida
- dia sim, dia não
- Adão e Eva
- de alto a baixo
- é pegar ou largar
- etc.

Na língua inglesa, há uma abundancia de binomios irreversíveis. Para citar só alguns:

- bed-and-breakfast
- alive and kicking
- back and forth
- bacon and eggs
- up and down
- sick and tired
- now or never
- ladies and gentlemen
- lost-and-found **1**
- Jesus, Mary and Joseph

**1** - Nesse exemplo é interessante notar que, no lado de cá do Atlântico (pt-BR), a ordem das palavras é ao contrário: "procure na seção de *achados e perdidos*".  Se fôssemos seguir a lógica, tudo tem que ser primeiro perdido para depois ser achado, e então seria "*seção de perdidos e achados*" como em pt-PT.

Já **a ordem dos adjetivos que descrevem um substantivo**, é um outro assunto que não tem relação com "café com leite".

- uma blusa verde de algodão egípcio
- um automóvel preto, velho e barulhento
- uma intrigante tela impressionista
- etc.

Isso pode ser assunto para uma outra pergunta.

Comment: Interessantíssimo, mas já usei muito “Eva e Adão”, “branco e preto” e “dia não, dia sim”. Ademito que sou uma pessoa de pouca memória, o que pode contribuir bastante. Não estou discordando da resposta, apenas dizendo que eu acho que talvez não seja tão restrito.+1

Comment: @Schilive  Não é proibido trocar a ordem das palavras e também não é errado. Mas não é assim que o povo fala.  Você pode dizer que as cores da Bandeira Brasileira são azul, amarelo, branco e verde, e não estaria errado.  Ou então, "eu vou com a coragem e a cara".  Mas certamente o seu interlocutor acharia estranho.

Comment: Centaurus, sim, mas estou dizendo que alguns desses não são tão conhecidos, pelo menos para mim. Eu não falaria "com a coragem e a cara", soa esquisito, mas falaria tranqüilamente e já falei "branco e preto" e "dia não, dia sim", mesmo sendo o inverso mais comum d'eu falar. Eu nem conhecia "verde, amarelo, azul e branco". Claro, eu posso ser uma exceção. Coisa engraçada.

Comment: Gostei. Trago a nota que "perdidos e achados" é como se diz "achados e perdidos" em Portugal; veja-se por exemplo este site oficial do Ministério [português] da Administração Interna: https://perdidoseachados.mai.gov.pt/ . Bem curiosa, esta simetria transatlântica, eh? :)

Answer (score 3):

Ambos estão corretos, mas indicam coisas diferentes.

Café com leite é café ao qual se adicionou leite.
Leite com café é leite ao qual se adicionou café.

A ideia implícita é que o componente "primário" é o principal, e que o secundário é apenas um acrescento ou complemento.

---

O teu desvio pelo inglês é um assunto diferente.

Em inglês [os adjetivos têm uma ordem particular](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order) por que têm de ser aplicados às palavras.
Isso é uma característica específica do inglês, e que não se aplica ao português.

Mesmo que se aplicasse ao português, é uma característica dos adjetivos - e as expressões na tua pergunta não têm adjetivo nenhum.

Comment: Discordo, o exemplo não foi bom.  **Café com leite é idiomático**, embora quase sempre tenha muito mais leite do que café.  Dizer leite com café para definir a bebida comum, é o mesmo que dizer "vou com a coragem e a cara".  Errado não é, mas não é assim que falamos.

Comment: Concordo contigo, café com leite é idiomático e "leite com café" não existe. Mas acho que em Portugal algo com mais leite que café seria um galão, e que o café com leite levaria mais café? Não tenho a certeza. Não há algum tuga que queira opinar?

Comment: Galão é a palavra antiga para que hoje se chama: caffe latte. Então se conta que um português voltou ao Portugal depois de muitos anos, entrou numa pasteleria, sentou numa mesa, e quando a garçoneta chegou,, Ele falou: caffe latte, por favor. E ela, nada jovem, respondeu: O que? Aqui não servimos café em lata.....

Comment: Talvez no Brasil. Em Portugal, um empregado de café estranharia que lhe pedissem um "um caffe latte", mas não "um galão". Só num franchise-café estrangeiro como o Starbucks ou o Costa Café é que não estranhariam - mas esses são ainda poucos.